# xpages datasource fields inside a dialog

Tags: xpages

button's code:

```
if ( Cdoc.isNewNote() ) { Cdoc.save(); }
Cdoc.setValue("txt_UNID",Cdoc.getDocument().getUniversalID());
getComponent('exampleDialog').show()
```

The dialog contains some fields, some of them binded to a datasource fields, and one field is getting the value from `txt_UNID` ( which belongs to `Cdoc` ). The dialog has one button: `Save`:

```
   <xp:button value="Save" id="button6" styleClass="lotusFormButton">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" 
imediate="false" save="false" refreshId="viewPanel1">                                                               refreshId="viewPanel1">
                 <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:Pdoc.save();     
                          getComponent('exampleDialog').hide();
              }]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
   </xp:button>
```

The Pdoc is saved and the doc. is listed inside the `viewPanel1`.

If I try again to add some new Pdoc using the button, it displays the previous Pdoc ( inside the dialog ) and all its fields are completed like in the previous case/Pdoc. If I `save` the dialog, it will overwrite the old Pdoc in the `viewPanel1`. Why I can not add multiple Pdocs using the dialog inside the `viewPanel1` ?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to change the data source scope for Pdoc to request (instead of view which is the default scope).

Add scope="request" to your data source definition and see if that helps:

```
<xp:dominoDocument var="Pdoc" ... scope="request">
```